# C# how to remove the last index of an array and store it as a character

Tags: c#

i have a character array, I would like to remove the last index and store it as a separate character name checkDigit

Comment: You can't remove anything from an array - once an array object has been created, it has a fixed size. You can *get* the last element of an array, of course. If you really want to remove an item, you'll need something like a `List<T>`. It would help if you'd give us more context, including what you've already tried and what happened.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show some code. If you talk about some sort of checksum (guessed by variable name), then why would need to literally "remove" an item?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
// Your chars
char[] chars = "ABCDEF0".ToCharArray();

// The last char
char checkDigit = chars[chars.Length - 1];

// Remove it from the array
Array.Resize(ref chars, chars.Length - 1);
```

Technically I'm not "removing" the `char` from the array. `Array.Resize` creates a new array, with a new size, and copies the elements from the "old" array to the "new" array, and puts a reference to the new array in `chars`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this as well:

```
char[] myCharArray = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
char removedChar = myCharArray[myCharArray.Length - 1]; // removed char
myCharArray = myCharArray.Take(myCharArray.Length - 1).ToArray(); // new array
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LwDij9)

Comment: @Toshi: Yep its fine to remove the extra variable

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Linq solution:

```
// Your chars
char[] chars = "ABCDEF0".ToCharArray();

// The last char
char checkDigit = chars.Last();

// Make new array without checkDigit
chars = chars.Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse();
```